# PySpark: Convert Dictionary in JSON DataFrame to Separate Columns

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, palantir-foundry

I have a JSON file that contains a dictionary that looks similar to this: `"object1":{"status1":388.646233,"status2":118.580561,"status3":263.673222,"status4":456.432483}`

I am trying to parse out `status1`, `status2`, `status3`, and `status4` to separate columns using PySpark.

**My Attempts:**

`F.explode(F.col('object1'))`

`.withColumn('status1', F.split(F.col('object1'))`

**Expected Result:**

| status1 | status2 | status3 | status4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 388.646233 | 118.580561 | 263.673222 | 456.432483 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pipeline Builder](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/pipeline-builder/overview/) and use the transform called `Extract rows from a JSON file`.

Note that there exist as well other transforms like `Parse out all fields of a Struct` to do that automatically if you were to have a JSON/Struct as one column already in a dataset.

If you already use a code repository and not pipeline builder, you can use `F.from_json(jsonStringcolumn,schema)` which [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) is available online